# How to get notified when the user changes CameraFlashMode?

Tags: xamarin.ios, ios7.1

I am using a plain vanilla `UIImagePickerController` with my own `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`. Doing so the flash mode set by the user gets always lost as I am disposing the whole controller after each capture, so opening the camera again always sets the flash mode "back" to *auto* (the default value).

I could refactor my camera utility and let it live as long as the app is alive, but the better way seems to be to just get notified when the users changes the flash mode, store that mode and set it before the camera is shown again.

Setting the mode is not the problem, but I don't get notified when it is changed by the user, nor does the property of the `UIImagePickerController` argument within the `FinishedPickingMedia` method of the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` contain the latest value set by the user, it's also always "auto".

```
private class CameraDelegate : UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
{
    public override void FinishedPickingMedia(UIImagePickerController picker, NSDictionary info)
    {
        // Is always UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashMode.Auto
        var foo = picker.CameraFlashMode;
    }
}
```

Any idea how to get that information?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try using Key-Value Observing to get notified when your property is changed.
You can find a tutorial on how to get KVO working with monotouch [here](http://tirania.org/monomac/archive/2012/Apr-19.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20MiguelsOsxAndIosBlog%20(Miguel%27s%20OSX%20and%20iOS%20blog)). 
And there's always the [official Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) on KVO

Comment: I will give it a try in a couple of days, should work by reading the docs. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I tried both cameraFlashMode and setCameraFlashMode: as documented here: http://iosapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=P%3AMonoTouch.UIKit.UIImagePickerController.CameraFlashMode. Whatever that flashmode button is doing after touch, it seems not to persist anything. I'm stuck at this point and I think I will go with a custom overlay in the future.